# Real World Use case of RxJava Subject

Tags: android, rx-java

There are a lot of great articles explaining about **RxJava**. But almost none of these explain the concept with real world example.

So I basically understand the concept of **RxJava Subject** like a **pipe** and it is both `observable` and `observer`.

But I don't see what will be the real-world usage of this **RxJava Subject** in Android Development world. Could you elaborate something on that?

Answer (score 1):

In my case was because I had one Observable that was waiting for an item of another Observable emitted which was asyncronious since it was Interval.

```
Scheduler scheduler = RxHelper.scheduler(vertx.getOrCreateContext());


Observable.just(callAnotherObservable)
          .subscribe(item -> System.out.println(item)

public Observable<String> callAnotherObservable(Scheduler scheduler, ){
          Subject subject = ReplaySubject.create(1);
          Observable.interval(100,TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
          .map(i->"item to be passed to the other observable")
          .subscribe(subject);
          return subject.observeOn(scheduler).first();//Here we wait for the first emission of the interval Observable.

}
```

Here as you can see we use subject.first() to wait for the first emission of the interval observable, which is running in another thread.

If you want to see more examples of "hotObservables" https://github.com/politrons/reactive/blob/master/src/test/java/rx/observables/connectable/HotObservable.java

Answer (score 1):

Subjects have a lots of "real world" applications particularly when you gradually transform your codebase from imperative to reactive style. It can serve as a bridge between these two worlds where you are able to affect a stream with non-reactive code coming outside of a stream.

But as you asked for an example. Recently I was implementing custom behavior when user tries to go back from an activity. RxJava provided me very elegant solution to the problem I was facing so I needed to compose a stream of events that corresponded to user wanting to go back. I deliberately avoided the phrase "press the back button", because there are several places in the codebase where I can simulate the going back situation and it always goes through `onBackPressed()` method.

Turning this into a single stream would require a massive refactoring, which is not on a budget right now. But I didn't want to give up the solution through RxJava as it could made the code a lot more concise. Using BehaviorSubject gave the answer as I just needed to emit an event within the `onBackPressed()` method.

Answer (score 1):

I was building a generic ReportDownloadManager for an Android application, where we needed to consume an Observable whose Observer would download and store a file locally. The event of successful or unsuccessful download needed to be handled by the manager, but also needed to expose an Observable to the Activities/Services that use this DownloadManager. I believe this was a good use-case for using a Subject to both consume the initial Observable but also generate events for the client Observable.

```
import android.app.DownloadManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.webkit.MimeTypeMap;

import java.io.File;

import io.reactivex.Observable;
import io.reactivex.functions.Consumer;
import io.reactivex.subjects.PublishSubject;

public class ReportDownloadManager {

    private final DownloadManager platformDownloadManager;

    public ReportDownloadManager(Context context) {
        this.platformDownloadManager = (DownloadManager) context.getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
    }

    public Observable<Object> download(final File file, DownloadAction downloadAction) {
        final PublishSubject<Object> subject = PublishSubject.create();
        downloadAction.execute(file.getName())
                .subscribe(new Consumer<Object>() {
                    @Override
                    public void accept(Object o) throws Exception {
                        platformDownloadManager.addCompletedDownload(file.getName(), "No description", false,
                                MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension("pdf"), file.getAbsolutePath(),
                                file.length(), true);
                        subject.onNext(new Object());
                        subject.onComplete();
                    }
                }, new Consumer<Throwable>() {
                    @Override
                    public void accept(Throwable throwable) throws Exception {
                        subject.onError(throwable);
                    }
                });
        return subject;
    }

    interface DownloadAction {
        Observable<Object> execute(String fileAbsolutePath);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need such a case as I show in the diagram

[image]